# How can I get the git-all meta package on RHEL 6.2

Tags: redhat, git, yum, rhel6

I believe I'm missing some of the common git addons, such as `gitk`, and I suspect it is because I installed git using

`sudo yum install git`

as the information for that package lists:

```
        : The git rpm installs the core tools with minimal dependencies.  To
        : install all git packages, including tools for integrating with
        : other SCMs, install the git-all meta-package.
```

Ok, fine. I'd like to install the `git-all` meta-package. However my naive attempt to do so, with `sudo yum install git-all` tells me there is no package `git-all`.

Here is my yum repolist:

```
repo id              repo name                                            status
epel                 Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 6 - x86_64       8,226
rhel-x86_64-server-6 Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server (v. 6 for 64-bit x86 8,800
```

What could I be missing?

Comment: I can suggest you to download the rpm here http://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=git-all (5th row) but I don't know what repo are you missing maybe you need to add the git repositories

Answer (score 3):

The `git-all` dummy package is part of the base repository. Short answer: `gitk` is its own package. `yum install gitk`.

```
[root@Davalan ~]# yum info git-all

Available Packages
Name        : git-all
Arch        : noarch
Version     : 1.7.1
Release     : 2.el6_0.1
Size        : 16 k
Repo        : base
Summary     : Meta-package to pull in all git tools
URL         : http://git-scm.com/
License     : GPLv2
Description : Git is a fast, scalable, distributed revision control system with an
            : unusually rich command set that provides both high-level operations
            : and full access to internals.
            : 
            : This is a dummy package which brings in all subpackages.
```

Running `yum install git-all` should resolve these dependencies. In a pinch, you can just make sure you have the following installed:

```
Dependencies Resolved

====================================================================================================================
 Package                          Arch                  Version                           Repository           Size
====================================================================================================================
Installing:
 git-all                          noarch                1.7.1-2.el6_0.1                   base                 16 k
Installing for dependencies:
 cvsps                            x86_64                2.2-0.6.b1.el6                    base                 56 k
 emacs-common                     x86_64                1:23.1-21.el6_2.3                 base                 18 M
 emacs-git                        noarch                1.7.1-2.el6_0.1                   base                 40 k
 emacs-nox                        x86_64                1:23.1-21.el6_2.3                 base                1.9 M
 git-cvs                          noarch                1.7.1-2.el6_0.1                   base                 84 k
 git-email                        noarch                1.7.1-2.el6_0.1                   base                 41 k
 git-gui                          noarch                1.7.1-2.el6_0.1                   base                216 k
 git-svn                          noarch                1.7.1-2.el6_0.1                   base                 95 k
 gitk                             noarch                1.7.1-2.el6_0.1                   base                132 k
 perl-Authen-SASL                 noarch                2.13-2.el6                        base                 51 k
 perl-DBI                         x86_64                1.609-4.el6                       base                705 k
 perl-GSSAPI                      x86_64                0.26-5.el6                        base                 64 k
 perl-Net-SMTP-SSL                noarch                1.01-4.el6                        base                8.1 k
 perl-TermReadKey                 x86_64                2.30-13.el6                       base                 31 k
 subversion-perl                  x86_64                1.6.11-7.el6                      base                796 k

Transaction Summary
====================================================================================================================
Install      16 Package(s)
```

Of course, you want want to know why your repo installation was unsuccessful. Are you pulling from the EL 6.2 or the 6.3 repository? (curious, since 6.2 is older and doesn't have any updates). You could also try a `yum clean all`.

Comment: Can you list what repositories you have available via `yum repolist`? My yum setup knows of no `git-all` package.

Answer (score 2):

You miss the optional repository:

```
rhn-channel --add --channel=rhel-x86_64-server-optional-6
```

Once you added this channel, you will find the `git-all` and `git-svn` packages.

```
[root@ls406135 ~]# yum install git-svn
Loaded plugins: rhnplugin
This system is receiving updates from RHN Classic or RHN Satellite.
...
========================================================================================================================================================================
 Package                                Arch                         Version                                  Repository                                           Size
========================================================================================================================================================================
Installing:
 git-svn                                noarch                       1.7.1-3.el6_4.1                          rhel-x86_64-server-optional-6                        95 k
Installing for dependencies:
 perl-TermReadKey                       x86_64                       2.30-13.el6                              core-0                                               31 k
 subversion-perl                        x86_64                       1.6.11-12.el6_6                          rhel-x86_64-server-optional-6                       797 k
Updating for dependencies:
 git                                    x86_64                       1.7.1-3.el6_4.1                          rhel-x86_64-server-6                                4.6 M
 perl-Git                               noarch                       1.7.1-3.el6_4.1                          rhel-x86_64-server-6                                 28 k
 subversion                             x86_64                       1.6.11-12.el6_6                          rhel-x86_64-server-6                                2.3 M

Transaction Summary
========================================================================================================================================================================
Install       3 Package(s)
Upgrade       3 Package(s)

Total download size: 7.8 M
Is this ok [y/N]:
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to activate a subscription entitlement for the machine before you will be able to install software from Red Hat Enterprise Linux repositories. If you believe the subscription for the machine *is* active, contact Red Hat for support.

Comment: Do you mean register with `rhn_register`? Yes, I have already done that. It was how I got the `rhel-x86_64-server-6` repository in the first place.

Comment: Is there a literal `base` repository that I should be seeing?

Comment: base == the core operating system packages.

Comment: Right. This is happening because the machine thinks the subscription is _not_ active. You need to contact Red Hat to figure out what's going on.